# CPU usage_slow performance

Tags: process

My Vaio laptop has become very slow recently. In task manager, all processes show CPU usage as 1% or 0% but in performance the CPU usage is about 30%. What could be the problem? Could it be that there is hidden virus running? Is there any way to check it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Really could be many things.
First check your memory usage. If thats rather high, end some of your unused processes to free up some memory. 
It could also be a virus.
I personally enjoy AVG Free or spybot S&D
If you also know a bit about what processes are normal on the system you use, you might be able to find a virus process by writting strange the process name into google. Theres always a lot of info on them on google. Gotta love it

Answer (score 0):

Lots of spyware and unneeded processes may do this. get [cCleaner](http://ccleaner.en.softonic.com/) and check all running processes, with CTRL+TAB+ESC , you may be able to safely deactivate many harmless hogs( bluetooth, skype, AIM etc). Avast, Malwarebytes, AVG are all pretty good too.

Comment: I tried both cCleaner and AVG, but the performance is still the same! Thanks for reply.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can have a better idea of what is your problem by opening **Windows Task Manager**:

- Right-click the taskbar, and then click **Start Task Manager**.
- Go to the process tab and order by memory usage to see which takes the most CPU & Memory usage.

You can kill some **unessessary** process and see if it solves the problem.

Hope it helps.